# Sass Mixin optional parameters

Tags: fonts, sass, mixins

I am writing this mixin below:

```
=font-placeholder($location, $name, $fallback: '', $fallback-style: '')
  %#{$location}-font
    font-family: "#{$name}", "#{$fallback}", $fallback-style

+font-placeholder($location: body, $name: FontName)
```

Instead of it outputting this:

```
%body-font {
  font-family: "FontName", "", "";
```

I want it to output this:

```
%body-font {
  font-family: "FontName";
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string doesn't need quotes, don't quote it.  Then you won't have to unquote it later.

What you need is a list of fonts, that way you won't have to worry about extra commas or empty strings.

```
=font-placeholder($location, $fonts...)
  %#{$location}-font
    font-family: $fonts

+font-placeholder(body, FontName)
+font-placeholder(body, FontName, serif)
+font-placeholder(body, FontName, Arial, sans-serif)
```

Should generate something like this:

```
%body-font {
  font-family: FontName;

%body-font {
  font-family: FontName, serif;

%body-font {
  font-family: FontName, Arial, sans-serif;
```